# Mistakes on a diagram see in TeX.SE

Tags: tikz-cd

What is the reason this code not working?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
A \arrow[rr, bend left]  & C \arrow[rd] & E  \\
B \arrow[rr, bend right] \arrow[u] \arrow[ru] & D \arrow[u] \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] & F \arrow[u]
\]


\end{document}
```

---

```
/main.tex :5    Undefined control sequence. [A \arrow]
/main.tex :5    Misplaced alignment tab character &. [A \arrow[rr, bend left]  &]
/main.tex :5    Undefined control sequence. [A \arrow[rr, bend left]  & C \arrow]
/main.tex :5    Misplaced alignment tab character &. [A \arrow[rr, bend left]  & C \arrow[rd] &]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [B \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [B \arrow[rr, bend right] \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [B \arrow[rr, bend right] \arrow[u] \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...rrow[rr, bend right] \arrow[u] \arrow[ru] &]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [...bend right] \arrow[u] \arrow[ru] & D \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [...] \arrow[u] \arrow[ru] & D \arrow[u] \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [... \arrow[ru] & D \arrow[u] \arrow[lu] \arrow]
/main.tex :6    Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...w[ru] & D \arrow[u] \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] &]
/main.tex :6    Undefined control sequence. [... \arrow[u] \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] & F \arrow]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `tikz-cd` notation

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rr, bend left]  & C \arrow[rd] & E  \\
B \arrow[rr, bend right] \arrow[u] \arrow[ru] & D \arrow[u] \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] & F \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cumulative diagram with letters and arrows]

Edit: I now see that you even have `tikz-cd` as a tag on the post